# Trigger for automatically updating email field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger which fires when a new row is inserted into my `StudentInformation` table without the `Email` field specified. The trigger should fire and update the email field with following pattern:

```
firstName.lastName@disney.com(e.g. Erik Kellener would be Erik.Kellener@disney.com)
```

If the insert statement already contains an email address, the trigger does not update the Email field. (e.g ignores the trigger's action)

So something like this:

```
create trigger trg_assignEmail

on StudentInformation
for insert
as begin
     if (email is null ) then
     update email 
     set email = (pattern)
....
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you  would typically do this with an `instead of insert`  trigger.

The idea is to `select` the values that were given for `insert` from pseudo-table `inserted`, and then apply the business rule on the `email` column.

Note that this requires listing all columns for insert. Assuming that you have `firstName`, `lastName` and `email`, that would be:

```
create trigger trgAssignEmail on StudentInformation
instead of insert
as
    set nocount on
    insert into StudentInformation(firstName, lastName, email)
    select 
        firstName,
        lastName,
        coalesce(email,  firstName + '.' + lastName + '@disney.com')
    from inserted
```

An alternative is to use an `after insert` trigger that `update`s the last inserted row(s) whose `email` is `null`. This is less efficient (since you need to scan the table for the modified row(s)), but saves you from listing all columns. For this, we need a primary key - let me assume `id`:

```
create trigger trgAssignEmail on StudentInformation
after insert
as
    set nocount on
    update s
    set s.email  = s.firstName + '.' + s.lastName + '@disney.com'
    from StudentInformation s
    inner join inserted i on i.id = s.id
    where s.email is null
```

Comment: thank you. Columns in my table are pretty a lot, is there any way not to require listing all columns for that?

Comment: @MuhammedTech: I understand. See my updated answer.